# How to default zoom in google map in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By default second city is hide. When click on second button, first city map will hide and second city map will show. But in there, second city map shows zoom out method. How to zoom in the Google map.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p67mq6wo/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bangalore").click(function(){
    $("#hyd").hide();
    $("#ban").show();
  });
  $("#hyderabad").click(function(){
    $("#ban").hide();
    $("#hyd").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reload the iframe once when it's initially hidden:

```
$("#hyderabad").click(function () {
    $("#ban").hide();
    $("#hyd").show();

}).one('click', function () {
    $("#hyd").prop('src', $("#hyd").attr('src'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p67mq6wo/6/

**Suggestion to save bandwith:**
only set the `src` of the initially visible iframe. For the other iframe(s) set an attribute `data-src` where you store the URL.

When you show the other iframes set the src to the `data-src` attribute:

```
$("#hyderabad").click(function () {
    $("#ban").hide();
    $("#hyd").show();

}).one('click', function () {
    $("#hyd").prop('src', $("#hyd").data('src'));
});
```

Especially when you have many hidden iframes the page will load much faster, because the maps will only be loaded when you show them.

http://jsfiddle.net/p67mq6wo/7/

Of course you may also use a single iframe and simply set the new `src` based on the clicked button.

Answer (score 2):

Hello in google map iframe we can not set directly as display:none 
see your demo

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/p67mq6wo/8/)

`See this link`